# Font not being mapped correctly in ghostscript

Tags: fonts, ghostscript

I am trying to convert a pdf document to a tiff using Ghostscript 9.10.
The pdf has TrueType (CID) Arial and Calibri fonts embedded in it.

The command line I am using is the following:

```
gswin32.exe -dSAFER -dBATCH -r200 -sDEVICE= tifflzw -sOutputFile=d:\temp\tmp.tiff D:\Temp\test.pdf
```

The conversion is successful but the Calibri portion comes out mangled

I tried adding different combinations of the following to the cidfmap:

```
/Calibri << /Path (c:/windows/Fonts/Calibri.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /FileType /TrueType /CSI [(Identity-H) 0] >> ;
/Calibri << /Path (c:/windows/Fonts/Calibri.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /FileType /TrueType /CSI [(Unicode) 0] >> ;
/Calibri << /Path (c:/windows/Fonts/Calibri.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /FileType /TrueType /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;
```

But when I run the command with the changes to the cidfmap I get the following

```
**** Warning: can't process font stream, loading font by the name.
**** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
**** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
```

The embedded arial font seems to be handled without an issue - and comes out correctly in the tiff.

```
Can't find CID font "Arial".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /Arial, see doc/Use.htm#CI
DFontSubstitution.
The substitute CID font "Adobe-Identity" is not provided either. attempting to u
se fallback CIDFont.See doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading a TT font from %rom%Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate
a CID font Adobe-Identity ... Done.
```

Does anybody have any idea how to deal with embedded calibri fonts?

Comment: where cidfmap file is placed on windows ?

Comment: FWIW I got lots of error messages like this with GS 9.15 but they seem to be gone with 9.20 ...and it working tons better with certain pdf's in 9.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the font is embedded in the PDF file then you don't need to supply a font mapping... The message being displayed tells you that Arial is *NOT* found, and that DroidSansFallback is being used instead.

Adding entries to cidfmap won't be any use *unless* you run Ghostscript with a -I switch so that it actually processes the cidfmap file. By default Ghostscript uses a ROM file system and all the support files are compiled into the executable.

Presumably you must be doing this to get the error. In any event the first thing I would suggest is that you remove -dSAFER from the command line as that will prevent Ghostscript from opening most files on disk, in particular the font files that you want to use.